# Why fopen gives "No such file or directory" error on passing output of read call ( char * ) to fopen's first parameter

Tags: c, fopen

This while loop is in server program and read call is linked to client via connfd which passes buff as name of file taken fom user via gets and passed through write call.
if i paste "filename.txt" in fopen 1st argument it works but this buff as an argument causes fopen to report error as "No such file or directory". :( any help appriciated

```
while(read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff))){
            write(1, buff, sizeof(buff));
            if((fp = fopen(buff, "r")) == NULL){
                perror("File Open error");
                write(connfd, "File Open error! File not found", sizeof("File Open error! File not found"));
            }else{
                send_file(fp, connfd);
                printf("\nFile sent Successfully! in server_helper");
            }
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual content of `buff` when you call `fopen`?  That seems to be one of the first debugging steps.

Comment: Do you nul-terminate `buff`?  It's hard to tell from the code snippet you have posted,  Also, you should loop calling `read` until you have read all the bytes you're expecting.  It's not guaranteed that you will get them all in one hit.

Comment: It would greatly help if you used the standard error message and just wrote, `perror(buff)`, but in this case there's a good chance that `buff` is missing the null-terminator, so that error message would be undefined behavior.  But....if that is indeed the problem then your program already exhibited undefined behavior when you called `fopen`.

Comment: You don't check the return for `read` to determine how many characters were read (which can be less than `sizeof(buff)`), but then you blindly `write()` out `sizeof(buff)` chars. Better do basic I/O validation - otherwise you invite *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Please don't use `gets`.  It's very dangerous. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: Surely `perror()` is reporting that error, not `fopen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff))
```

Let's assume that `read` returns a positive value and `buff` is a static char array (`char buff[N]`), then you have a char array filled with some data but not a null-terminated string. In order to pass `buff` to `fopen` you have to append a `'\0'` at the end of the data in the buffer `buff`.

For that you need the result of read

```
ssize_t bytes_read = read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1); //1 byte for '\0'
buff[bytes_read] = '\0'; //if bytes_read >= 0
```

After that, if you need the length of the string/data then you have to use `strlen(buff)`. Since there could be fewer characters in the buffer than the buffers size (`sizeof(buff) != strlen(buff)`).

Comment: I got it Thanks @Erdal Küçük i used strlen as sizeof gives full buff and i  needed only the portion having data not all of it

Comment: @aliahmed As you need to use the result from `read` to terminate your string, why not just use that value instead of calling `strlen`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it Thanks @Erdal Küçük i used strlen as sizeof gives full buff and i needed only the portion having data not all of it

```
while(read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1)){   
            int len = strlen(buff);
            printf("%d",len);
            buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
            write(1, buff, sizeof(buff));
            if((fp = fopen(buff, "r")) == NULL){
                perror("File Open error");
                write(connfd, "File Open error! File not found", sizeof("File Open error! File not found"));
            }else{
                send_file(fp, connfd);
                printf("\nFile sent Successfully! in server_helper");
            }
            bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        }
```

Comment: I doubt that this works. The function `read` reads bytes into a buffer (`buf`). You can make this buffer to a 'null-terminated' string, by appending the '\0' character to the end of the valid data (result of `read`). You cannot use `strlen` on a non null-terminated string, since `strlen` counts the number of characters until '\0' is found.

Comment: Actually i passed "ali.txt" as file name from client to server which is read by read call and when i checked lelngth of buff it was 8 but it should be 7 ("ali.txt")  so i just made last character null-terminator by appending '\0' which worked as now fopen is opening all files which ever name i pass if it exits there.